# JdbcTemplate vs JPA query

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I am facing strange problem where SAME query works via jdbctemplate.queryForList but does not work via JpaRepository @Query.
Both jdbctemplate and jpa entityManagerFactory+transactionManager use the same datasource, connecting to SQL Server.
When jpa query runs is returns: SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000; ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Jdbctemplate query returns data from the db.

config xml:

```
<bean id="dataSourceSQL" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=SQLServerName"/>
    <property name="username" value="***"/>
    <property name="password" value="***"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplateSQL" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSourceSQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactorySQL" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceSQL">
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerSQL" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorySQL" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerSQL" />
```

Repository.java

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY, value="transactionManagerSQL") 
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long>{
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select u.name from schema.Users u")
List<String> findUsers();
}
```

Test.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath*:spring/config.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManagerSQL",    defaultRollback = true)

public class Test {
@Autowired Repository repository;
@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateSQL;

@Test
@Transactional("transactionManagerSQL")
public void testJpa() {
     List<String> records = repository.findUsers(); //fails with table not found exception
     assertNotNull(records);
}

@Test
public void testJdbcTemplate(){
    List<Map<String, Object>> records=jdbcTemplateSQL.queryForList("select u.name from schema.Users u"); //returns results
    assertNotNull(records);
}
}
```

Comment: It is though. I also tried using jpa queries with the same result.

Comment: It isn't JPQL it is just a valid SQL query. Nothing invalid about it. One thing to try is to use it without a schema and specify a default schema on the datasource or EMF.